# Are the 2 autocommits the same thing: SQLAlchemy and MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

`autocommit` in SQLAlchemy:

```
sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False)  # autocommit default False
```

`autocommit` in MySQL:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0  -- autocommit default 1
```

I am wondering, are the two autocommits the same thing? i.e. SQLAlchemy passes `autocommit` status to MySQL via something equivolent to `SET AUTOCOMMIT`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit), these aren't identical (although they achieve the same result).

SQLAlchemy *always* uses transactions, so it always sets `AUTOCOMMIT=0` on MySQL. However, if you set `autocommit=True`, it will automatically call `.commit()` whenever you make a change to the data.

This is done in that way because every database does autocommit differently (if at all), and SQLAlchemy tries to behave consistently between them.